# bazel new_http_archive re-try supported?

Tags: bazel

We have an external dependency that we are using 
new_http_archive for.

There was a situation when the external download failed and as a result one of the pre-submits failed. There does not seem to be a way to re-try with new_http_archive.

It would be useful to re-try so there is less churn with external connectivity hiccups which do happen as we see.

Any idea how to accompish that? Is there a way to tell bazel to try again if external URL download fails?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2):

You can prefetch dependencies using the command `bazel fetch` before calling `bazel build`. If the fetch returns a non-zero error code you could bazel re-run `bazel fetch` as many times as you want to try the external URL download.

Answer (score 1):

Retry support is already built into `new_http_archive`: it should already attempt to download the file 8 times before giving up (unless it gets an error that suggests it would be fruitless to retry, e.g., "403: permission denied").

You can also specify multiple URLs for Bazel to try, e.g.,

```
new_http_archive(
    name = "whatever",
    urls = [
        "https://mirror1.example.com/your_archive.zip",
        "https://mirror2.example.com/your_archive.zip",
    ],
```

...